# Using Set-Date in a Powershell script fails due to permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.1, local-security-policy

When trying to run `Set-Date` in my powershell script it fails because it claims to require more permissions. I have added the groups Users and even Everyone to the Adjust system time Local Security Policy. Of course I could run it elevated to admin, but I'm trying to avoid that. What's extra odd is that this script has worked fine so far on some machines.

Powershell version is 5.1, windows version is 10 Enterprise 2016 (v1607)

The error message:

```
PS > Set-Date "2021-06-07T10:00"
Set-Date : Klienten har ikke nødvendig tilgangsnivå
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Date "2021-06-07T10:00"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Date], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetDateCommand
```

Comment: Could be that setting the system time is blocked for standard users in group policy.  I would double check using gpresult

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I will definitely check that tomorrow morning. I would check now, but the machine isn't responding to remote desktop.

Comment: @Daniel As far as I can tell, there are no group policies restricting adjusting system time

Comment: @HenrikErstad I cannot reproduce your error on a Windows 10 Pro v1809 (it works as expected). Do you make sure the user that gets permissions to modify the system time creates a **new** logon session **after** you changed the Local Security Policy?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on my own machine, or even similar machines to the problematic ones. I have rebooted the machines after setting the Local Security Policy

Comment: You should update your question with a copy-and-paste of the _exact_ error message (not a screen shot).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I didn't do that initially as it's in Norwegian, but I'll add it anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I do not fully understand why, it works when you disable the policy `User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode`.